# Should an API assume the proper calling sequence, or should it verify the assumptions?

Tags: c, api

I have 2 api calls to implement, let's call them "ShouldDoSomething" and "DoSomething".  The first is a test to see if a particular action needs to be taken and the other actually takes that action.  Naturally, taking the action is only necessary or valid if the test returns true.  There are cases where the test is needed without actually taking the action, so both are necessary.

Should the action call internally run the test and become a no-op if it's not needed, or should the implementation assume that it will only ever be called in the case where the test has already returned true?  It seems simpler and safer to validate the assumptions, but then the 'action' call has 3 possible return states instead of two (success, failure, and not needed).  Another approach would be to make the test an assertion and abort if the action was called unnecessarily.  (this is in C, so exceptions aren't really a good idea)

But it comes down to a choice - simpler api calls or fewer api calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a policy according to what you think is cleanest for the intended use cases.  Document it clearly and carefully.  The most important thing with API decisions like this is documentation, not the specifics of what convention is chosen.

If you decide to use the first option, do you actually need to add a "not needed" return state, or can it simply indicate "success" if the operation is not needed?  Don't add complexity unless it's necessary.

Comment: The success/failure return probably isn't needed, but the was needed/not needed status is important (to take an alternate action)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be best to go with:

> Another approach would be to make the
>   test an assertion and abort if the
>   action was called unnecessarily.

So for example if "DoSomething" is called and "ShouldDoSomething" is telling you that you shouldn't take that particular action then "DoSomething should abort without doing anything. Do you really need to expose "ShouldDoSomething" to the client, if its only testing whether "DoSomething" should be called?

I think it also comes down to what will be changed. Could it be fatal if called inappropriately? If so I think you should put assertions in. If it will be harmless then it doesn't really matter.

I would say safer is the way to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "ShouldDoSomething" is needed because there are other places in the code where an alternate action needs to be taken if the "something" won't happen, but the "something" can't happen yet.  It could be done as "ShouldDo" and "DoIfNeeded", but that seems more awkward to me.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Canon is correct about consistency and documentation.

Personally I tend to err on trying to protect people from themselves unless it is a serious performance penalty.  In most situations I would lean to checking ShouldDoSomething internally from DoSomething and return an error if DoSomething wasn't required.  That indicates a logic error to the user and is a lot nicer than letting them blow up or leaving something in an invalid state that might be hard to debug down the line.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest API (from a user perspective) would be to have the function `DoSomethingIfNeeded()`, and let you take care of the conditions. Why bother the user?

The least friendly user interface is the one that says: "Now call one of these functions! No, not that one!".

Comment: In one case, an alternate action needs to be taken if the 'something' action was not taken, and in another case an alternate action needs to be taken if the 'something' will not be taken at some future point.  I agree it would be cleaner to have just one function, but the structure doesn't lend itself to that.